# Channerl url in mobile webapp

Tags: deezer

I am plannig to create a FirefoxOS app using Deezer API. So it would be a WebApp but it doesn't run on a server.

My main doubt is about the chanel url for cross domain requests.
Which one can I use or how can I manage that as soon as I have not a server URL neither a native package name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auth necessarily needs a domain or a bundle id to work properly. API cross domain requests can work without the channel URL though, you'll find code snippets to make jsonp queries here: https://github.com/deezer/code-snippets/blob/master/deezer-sdk-js/simple-deezer-api-request.js